# Issue with timeouts when using ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

I have a list of several hundred thousand `Callable` objects. When each one is run, it performs a potentially lengthy calculation based on the values given to it. Because of this, I want to run each task asynchronously (preferably through the use of some kind of Executor) and retrieve the results of each calculation after 30 seconds, cancelling those which do not complete in time. (The values obtained are used elsewhere.)

This is how I've implemented it so far:

```
private void process() {
    class Runner implements Callable<BigDecimal> {
        final int x, y;

        Runner(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal call() {
            BigDecimal gWidth = xMax.subtract(xMin), gHeight = yMax.subtract(yMin);
            BigDecimal gy = gHeight.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(-y)).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(height)).add(yMax);
            BigDecimal gx = gWidth.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(x)).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(width)).add(xMin);

            // The calculation begins when this method is called
            BigDecimal result = calculateAt(gx, gy);
            return result;
        }
    }

    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    List<Runner> runners = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            runners.add(new Runner(x, y));
        }
    }

    try {
        List<Future<BigDecimal>> results = exec.invokeAll(runners, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        for (Future<BigDecimal> future : results) {
            // Check if the future's task was cancelled and process the results
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    exec.shutdown();
}

// Extra variables and methods
BigDecimal xMin = BigDecimal.valueOf(-7),
           xMax = BigDecimal.valueOf(7),
           yMin = BigDecimal.valueOf(-7),
           yMax = BigDecimal.valueOf(7);
int height = 850, width = 850;
private BigDecimal calculateAt(BigDecimal x, BigDecimal y) {
    try {
        // Just to simulate a potential execution time
        Thread.sleep((ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(45) + 1) * 1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return BigDecimal.ONE;
}
```

The ArrayList `runners` stores each `Callable` to be executed, which is then sent to the ExecutorService to run all the tasks. The issue I'm running into is that the tasks seem to be started synchronously, and after the timeout of 30 seconds, only the first 40 or 50 thousand tasks have finished, much less started executing.

What appears to be happening is that the `ExecutorService.invokeAll` method is allowing only a 30 second window for *all* the tasks in the list to start *and* finish executing. What I instead need is for this 30 second window to begin on a per-task basis, i.e. allow 30 seconds for the task to finish *once it's already started.* `invokeAll` doesn't seem to do this, at least not with a `newCachedThreadPool`. Is there a Java library or other method of implementation that does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can solve the problem with [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html).

For example, here is a code based on the snippet from the question:

```
private static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
private static final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(100);

private static void processAsync() {
  List<CompletableFuture<Object>> futureList = IntStream.range(0, height).boxed()
    .flatMap(y -> IntStream.range(0, width).boxed().map(x -> new Runner(x, y)))
    .map(runner ->
      CompletableFuture.anyOf(
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(runner, executor),
        timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
      ).exceptionally(throwable -> {
        // timeout is handled here
        return BigDecimal.ZERO;
      })
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

  CompletableFuture.allOf(futureList.toArray(new CompletableFuture<?>[0]))
    .thenAccept(v -> {
      List<BigDecimal> results = futureList.stream()
        .map(CompletableFuture::join)
        .map(r -> (BigDecimal) r)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
      // process final results
      BigDecimal sum = results.stream().reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
      System.out.println("Final sum: " + sum);
    })
    .exceptionally(throwable -> {
      System.out.println("Failed allOf with " + throwable);
      return null;
    });
}

private static CompletableFuture<BigDecimal> timeout(Duration duration) {
  CompletableFuture<BigDecimal> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
  scheduler.schedule(
    () -> future.completeExceptionally(new TimeoutException("Timeout " + Thread.currentThread().getName())), duration.toMillis(), MILLISECONDS);
  return future;
}

private static class Runner implements Supplier<BigDecimal> {...
```

The main idea here is to use `CompletableFuture.anyOf` and apply it to `CompletableFuture` of your useful task and `CopmpletableFuture` of timeout task. Timeout is achieved by using `ScheduledExecutorService` and `CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally`. So, basically, `anyOf` returns either result or `TimeoutException`.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Small error: `supplyAsync(runner, executor)` should be `supplyAsync(() -> runner, executor)`. And no need to use `boxed()` on the second `IntStream`. Two questions: does this preserve the order of the `Runner`s? (Looking at it, I assume it does.) And if the timeout does occur, will `CompletableFuture.anyOf(...).exceptionally()` catch the `TimeoutException`?

Comment: I may have it return `BigDecimal.ZERO` instead of `null` in that case.

Comment: Forgot to include, I've changed `private static class Runner implements Supplier<BigDecimal>`. About questions: 1) Order is preserved at create time, but as everything will be executed asynchronously - results will come in arbitrary order. 2) Yes `CompletableFuture.anyOf(...).exceptionally()` catches `TimeoutException`. And also, if needed you can return `BigDecimal.ZERO` instead of `null`.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest approach is to invoke each task individually, e.g. in the loop in which you are initializing the `Runner`s. As the behaviour you've mentioned above is compliant with the [JavaDoc documentation of `ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), no subclass (at least the ones coming with the Java Standard Edition) will behave differently. A distinct function implementing this behaviour doesn't exist either.

From the documentation of `#invokeAll(List<? extends Callable>, long, TimeUnit)`:

> Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their status and results when all complete or the timeout expires, whichever happens first. Future.isDone() is true for each element of the returned list. Upon return, tasks that have not completed are cancelled. Note that a completed task could have terminated either normally or by throwing an exception. The results of this method are undefined if the given collection is modified while this operation is in progress.